ALT key not working on fresh installation of ubuntu 22.04
I installed Ubuntu 22.04.5 today. After installing it everything was fine except the ALT key. Whenever I press the ALT key(both left and right), it presses a whole lot of other keys like '7', '<', '/', 'g', 'h', and "F5" all at once.
I have tried changing keyboard layouts but it didn't work. I am currently using English(United States) keyboard layout.
When I tried xev, and I pressed down the Alt key, the following was the output:
EnterNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x48c, subw 0x0, time 3697583, (175,48), root:(273,162),
    mode NotifyNormal, detail NotifyNonlinear, same_screen YES,
    focus YES, state 16
 
KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  15  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
 
MotionNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x48c, subw 0x0, time 3697583, (175,48), root:(273,162),
    state 0x10, is_hint 0, same_screen YES
 
KeyPress event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x48c, subw 0x0, time 3701875, (175,48), root:(273,162),
    state 0x10, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
mbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False
 
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x48c, subw 0x0, time 3701915, (175,48), root:(273,162),
    state 0x10, keycode 79 (keysym 0xffb7, KP_7), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (37) "7"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (37) "7"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
 
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x48c, subw 0x0, time 3701920, (175,48), root:(273,162),
    state 0x10, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
 
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x48c, subw 0x0, time 3701931, (175,48), root:(273,162),
    state 0x10, keycode 106 (keysym 0xffaf, KP_Divide), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
 
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x48c, subw 0x0, time 3701949, (175,48), root:(273,162),
    state 0x10, keycode 9 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) "
FilterEvent returns: False
 
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x48c, subw 0x0, time 3701955, (175,48), root:(273,162),
    state 0x10, keycode 79 (keysym 0xffb7, KP_7), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (37) "7"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
 
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x48c, subw 0x0, time 3701970, (175,48), root:(273,162),
    state 0x10, keycode 94 (keysym 0x3c, less), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (3c) "<"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
 
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0xa00001,
    root 0x48c, subw 0x0, time 3701978, (175,48), root:(273,162),
    state 0x10, keycode 106 (keysym 0xffaf, KP_Divide), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (2f) "/"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Can someone help resolve this or do I have to install it again?

What does xev show when you press down Alt ?

When I use xev it shows that the keycodes of '7', '<', '/', 'g', 'h', and 'F5' when press down Alt

I edited my question. Kindly take a look.

as part of your investigation process, spin up a copy of 22.04 on a Live USB, select test Ubuntu and see if the same issue is repeated.

Yes the same issue is repeated
